# Best way to create numeric hash/ID from a string?

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I'm building a MySQL database with a table that will store *lots* of rows (say, like 1.000.000).
Each row will have a numeric ID but I don't want to make it incremental, instead it has to be generated from a unique string.

For example, a user ABC will create a new element at time 123, so the original string will be "ABC-123". A PHP function will "translate" it to a number.
This way, I'll have the possibility to re-generate the same ID from the same pair of data in future. More or less... see it as a Java hashCode() function.

I've found this function that "translates" a string into a number:

```
function hashCode($string) {
    return base_convert(substr(md5($string), 0, 16), 16, 10);
}
```

I have some doubts about it. First, it starts from creating an md5 hash which is 32 characters long, then cuts it to 16. It's a visible lack of data so how could that be an unique hash?

Second, the produced 16-digits number is converted from base-16 to base-10, so the max value is `18446744073709552046`. The MySQL column that will store this number has an `UNSIGNED BIGINT` datatype so the maximum value is `18446744073709551615`. It's not enough since

```
18446744073709551615 - 18446744073709552046 = -431
```

Am I missing something, or is there a better way to do what I need?

Comment: Why not just use an auto increment? What implications would that bring?

Comment: The reason is written in the second paragraph: "This way, I'll have the possibility to re-generate the same ID from the same pair of data in future". With autoincrement, I have no information about the link between an example string "ABC-123" and the autoincrement value generated months before

Comment: @alessandro.francesconi try searching for MYSQL increament functions/procedures there are a lot of different ways (purposed already). 
Its just up to you to pick some of them and customize it to fit your requirements ..

Comment: So why not use "ABC-123" as the primary id then?

Comment: Performance/space reasons: storing a string as primary key is worse than storing a number

Comment: Even if those strings are very long (let's assume 50 characters), even across a million records the difference will add up to less than 50 MB, which is likely a fraction of the overall database size. Is this *really* a necessary tradeoff that's worth bending over backwards for?

Comment: I can understand the *space* tradeoff... but what about lookup speed? This table will be read-intensive

Comment: With an appropriate index set, there should be no issue in read speed. Numeric ids also just gain their speed by using an index, not because numbers are inherently faster.

Comment: I'll consider it but, please, can we go back to the main problem? This "string to int" conversion will be used for other works, so let's assume that I'm forced to use integers  ;)

Comment: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 = 2^64 − 1 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.  I'm not sure where you are getting 18,446,744,073,709,552,046 from.